# Order by the date of determined event, (not timestamp created by Firebase, a node that I use)

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

So, I'm making an app to list running events, it has 2 tabs, 1 showing events that will happen, ordered by date, the top near the current date, and the other showing events that happened recently, also ordering the ones on the top by the ones near my current date. I have the Tabs ready, login, loggout, the recycler view. Close to all that I need, but I can't think of a way of getting the data on and reading from Firebase Database. After a few tries, I'm thinking of sorting the nodes by date, in this format:

```
node RunEvent
      node 20171202
            node nameEvent
                   other atribs
            node nameEvent2
                   other atrib
      node 20171207
            node nameEvent3
                   other atribs
```

My question is:

-How can I list my events, I tried a few listeners, but no luck (or skill, I'm starting on dev).
I'll add the code when I get home.

Comment: You've listed a rather broad set of use-cases and asked a set of questions. This is typically not the best way to get help on Stack Overflow. It's hard for us to say whether this data structure will work for all your use-cases. But if you have a specific use-case and trouble implementing it on this data structure, we can likely be more helpful. Same with your last question: if you have tried something and can't get it to work, you are much more likely to get help if you share the [minimal code that reproduces where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your database looks simmilar to this:

```
Firebase-root
   |
   --- RunEvent
         |
         --- 20171202
         |      |
         |      --- nameEvent: "First Event"
         |
         --- 20171207
                |
                --- nameEvent: "Second Event"
```

Please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference runEventRef = rootRef.child("RunEvent");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String nameEvent = ds.child("nameEvent").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", nameEvent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
runEventRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Your output will be:

```
First Event
Second Event
```